# correct usage of GetClipRgn?

Tags: c++, winapi

I want to write a function that needs to set the clipping region on a DC but restore any existing clipping region on the DC when it is done.

So I found [`GetClipRgn`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144866.aspx) which sounds like exactly what I want but seems confusing.  I couldn't find any examples of using it and Petzold had nothing to offer.

What I came up with was this:

```
void DrawStuff( HDC hDC )
{
    HRGN restoreRegion = CreateRectRgn( 0, 0, 0, 0 );
    if (GetClipRgn( hDC, restoreRegion ) != 1)
    {
        DeleteObject( restoreRegion );
        restoreRegion = NULL;
    }

    // 
    // Set new region, do drawing
    //

    SelectClipRgn( hDC, restoreRegion );
    if (restoreRegion != NULL)
    {
        DeleteObject( restoreRegion );
    }
}
```

It just seems weird that I need to create a region in order to get the current region.

Is this correct usage?

Is there are better way to achieve the same effect?

Comment: Do you truly need a "small" region (generally called a "Region Of Interest - ROI) that is a sub-part of the full client area? GetClientRect() will give you the full drawable area. Clip regions are for getting a part of that area.

Comment: Yeah, it's a weird function.  Your code looks okay.

Comment: @Hans - thanks I feel better about it now.  Probably the strangest win32 function I ever used...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well the closest thing to a correct answer is Hans Passant's comment:

> Yeah, it's a weird function. Your code looks okay.

Answer (score 4):

I use the [`SaveDC`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162945.aspx) and [`RestoreDC`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162929.aspx) functions:

> The **SaveDC** function saves the current state of the specified device
>   context (DC) by copying data describing selected objects and graphic
>   modes (such as the bitmap, brush, palette, font, pen, region, drawing
>   mode, and mapping mode) to a context stack.

It feels cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

Will `int SelectClipRgn( __in  HDC hdc, __in  HRGN hrgn);` do the job?

The SelectClipRgn function selects a region as the current clipping region for the specified device context.

Only a copy of the selected region is used. The region itself can be selected for any number of other device contexts or it can be deleted.

The SelectClipRgn function assumes that the coordinates for a region are specified in device units.

To remove a device-context's clipping region, specify a NULL region handle.