# What's the correct way to save the clipping region of a DC and restore it later?

Tags: c, winapi, gdi, clipping

So remember [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25551622/3408572)? Well as it turns out, if I click a button a tab control with this code applied to it, the entire window blanks out until I mouse over. I determined that this is because the clipping region of the device context passed to the `WM_CTLCOLORxxx` messages isn't set:

```
(results from windows 7 64-bit)
on a normal redraw
window rect 435 301 591 324
client rect 4 96 160 119
clip rect 4 96 230 119

after clicking a button
window rect 435 301 591 324
client rect 4 96 160 119
clip rect 0 0 320 240 (this is the top level window's client rect)
```

So now I want to temporarily clip the DC to the button's client rect. I don't want to just call `IntersectClipRect()` in case Windows's internal workings (or something else entirely) passes in a different cilp rect, so I'd rather save the clipping rect and restore it. My question is what the best way of doing so is.

Is it `SaveDC()`?

```
i = SaveDC(dc);
IntersectClipRect(dc, r.left, r.top, r.right, r.bottom);
// ...
RestoreDC(dc, i);
```

MSDN's documentation doesn't list clipping as one of the things saved with `SaveDC()`.

Is it `GetClipRgn()` and `SelectClipRgn()`?

```
rgn = CreateRectRegion(0, 0, 0, 0); // see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3478180/correct-usage-of-getcliprgn
GetClipRgn(dc, rgn);
IntersectClipRect(dc, r.left, r.top, r.right, r.bottom);
// ...
SelectClipRgn(dc, rgn);
```

I'm not sure if this will actually replace the existing clipping region entirely, or just do another intersect.

Or is it something else?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SaveDC()`/`RestoreDC()` includes the clipping region.

Comment: Update: I only now reached a point where I could start implementing this; manually clipping does not actually solve the problem I thought it would (in the question) :( I also tried using a clipping region and just using a BitBlt() from a compatible DC; nothing. What's more, I couldn't reproduce the issue with a MCVE, at least not yet. We'll see... this is going to elude me for a while. Still, this does answer the question I asked, and is useful to know anyway, so thanks regardless!